# Power transistors identification

Tags: transistors, identification

I have an older Kustom powered mixer model PA40B. This is not the new battery operated amp. I am in need of the four power transistors that are mounted on a large heatsink.

The numbers on the transistors are 7-0000 across the top, the letter H is in the lower left, and the numbers 8141 are in the lower right.

I can't find any references to these numbers anywhere I have looked. I could use some help if there is any out there.

Comment: please add pictures